# How to update gradle without android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-sdk-manager

I have run into some issues with gradlew failing to run in my nativescript application. People have told me that it's a gradle issue and I need to update it, but wherever I search I see instructions for updating gradle using android studio. But I've just installed my SDKs using the sdkmanager and avdmanager. Is there any way to update gradle using them?
I don't want to update my emulator images etc. only gradle.

Comment: Download it? https://gradle.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update android studio you should be able to keep settings from past versions I've been using android studio on the same computer for 3 to 4 years and all my old images/ SDKs  are still there, plus if you update grade without updating android studio the grade may not be recognized by that version of android studio. If I was in your place I would update android studio to the latest stable version.

Comment: I said I don't have or use android studio!

Comment: follow the instructions [here](https://gradle.org/install/). then you can go to to your project in the terminal `gradle build` and then `gradle run`. I would recommend against it android studio is very powerful tool that I would strongly recommend you keep using if you can.

Comment: follow these i[nstructions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html) to update the gradle in your project